# Photo manipulation/filter library techniques for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Just wondering how difficult it would be to convert the following library to Objective-C to be used on the iPhone?

I guess I'm after some similar image processing libraries that would lead me in the right direction? I'm aware that it's not easy to apply the same filters as existing applications like Instragram, Path and Hipstamatic.

However, I'd like to be able to do something similar.

Here is the JavaScript library:

https://github.com/alexmic/filtrr/blob/master/filtrr.js

A demo of its functionality can be found here:

http://alexmic.net/demos/filtrr

Comment: This is manifestly not [a real SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#ask). What is the problem you need help with? What kind of response are you looking for?

Comment: Nothing to do with javascript, tag should be removed.

Comment: @Josh I disagree with you. I'm asking for help with anything relating to the conversion of JS to Objective-C. Perhaps there are some helpful tutorials out there to push me in the right direction? Maybe there's a couple of libraries out there that do something similar to what I want to do with image conversion? Does that answer your question?

Comment: @RobG "javascript" Tag removed.

Comment: @Fulvio: Still not very specific, IMO, but I've cast my vote and can only wait to see if others agree.

Comment: My day's going quite well. "Just wondering how difficult it would be to do X" is not a "practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face". "every answer is equally valid" "there is no actual problem to be solved" "an open-ended, hypothetical question" "If your motivation for asking the question is 'I would like to participate in a discussion about X', then you should not be asking here." Quotes from the FAQ. All I meant by "I can only wait..." is that my vote is does not count by itself (which is a good thing). Four others have to agree. It's nothing personal, good or bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've started a bit of converting, here is a sample. Now of course, fully converting it would a lot of time, too much for me to do it. But just see how I've done it. I'm hoping you have prior experience with Obj-C?

Also, perhaps you could look at some existing libraries.

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/05/mgimageutilities/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, dont forget that XCode can compile C++ into your project so also investigate C or C++ libraries.

```
 NSObject canvas;
 int w;
 int h;
 int ctx;
 NSData imageData;

 @implementation filtr
 {
    -(id) initWithCanvas:(id)_canvas
    {
        if (!_canvas) {
            throw "Canvas supplied to filtr was null or undefined.";
        }

        canvas    = _canvas;
        w         = canvas.width;
        h         = canvas.height;
        ctx       = canvas.getContext("2d");
        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    /**
     * Clamps the intensity level between 0 - 255.
     *
     * @param i The intensity level.
     */
     -(int)safe:(int)i
    {
        return MIN(255, MAX(0, i));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me a stepping stone. This is exactly what I was after. I will take a good look at those existing libraries you provided.